# copy of the table after user changes some inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have table with some input fields where user can enter the inputs in it.once user enters and click on Add button.copy has to be done with user input fields.

I want to show exact copy of the table after user changes the fields by clicking on button.

```js
function duplicate(val)
 {
  
  
   
   var editTable=$('#editable').html()  
    
   var totalGarments=$('#totalGarments').val()   
    
   test = parseInt(totalGarments)+1
   
   $('#totalGarments').val(test) 
   
   var testVal=$('#totalGarments').val()  
 
   var duplicatVal= parseInt(val)+1
  
   var selectOtmGarmentsHtml=$('#otmgarments'+val).html()
   var selectOtmColorsHtml=$('#otmcolors'+val).html()
   var selectOtmSizeHtml=$('#otmsize'+val).html()
   

   $('#editable'+val).after("<table cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' border='0' class='table table-striped table-bordered' id='editable"+testVal+"'><thead><tr><td>Garments</td><td>Color</td><td>Size</td> <td>Quantity</td> <td><span onclick='addNew("+testVal+")' class='btn btn-sm block btn-success'>Add</span></td> </tr> <tbody>  <tr><td><select class='form-control' name='otmgarments[]' id='otmgarments"+testVal+"'>"+selectOtmGarmentsHtml +"</select></td> <td><select class='form-control' name='otmcolors[]' id='otmcolors"+testVal+"'>"+selectOtmColorsHtml +"</select>   </td> <td><select class='form-control' name='otmsize[]' id='otmsize"+testVal+"'>"+selectOtmSizeHtml +"</select>  </td> <td> <input type='text' value='' name='otmquantity[]' id='otmquantity"+duplicatVal+"' class='form-control'></td>   <td><span onclick='duplicate("+testVal+")' class='btn  block btn-sm btn-danger'>Duplicate</span></td></tr> </tbody> </table>")
     
 
    
  var garmentSearch=$('#otmgarments'+val).val()
  var colorSearch=$('#otmcolors'+val).val()
  var sizeSearch=$('#otmsize'+val).val()
  var quantityValue=$('#otmquantity'+val).val()
  
  
   
  $('#otmgarments'+duplicatVal+' option[value='+garmentSearch+']').attr('selected',true);
  $('#otmcolors'+duplicatVal+' option[value='+colorSearch+']').attr('selected',true);
  $('#otmsize'+duplicatVal+' option[value='+sizeSearch+']').attr('selected',true);
  $('#otmquantity'+duplicatVal).val(quantityValue)
  
  
  
 }
```

```html
<div class="form-group" >
                          <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Quantity</label>
                          <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" name="totalGarments" id="totalGarments" value="1">
        
                            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="editable1">
       
         <thead>
                                <tr>
                                  <td>Garments</td>
                                  <td>Color</td>
                                  <td>Size</td>
                                  <td>Quantity</td>
                                  <td><span onclick='addNew(1)' class="btn btn-sm block btn-success">Add</span></td>
                                </tr>
                              </thead>
         
                              <tbody>
         
           <tr>
                                  <td>
          
           
         <select class="form-control" name="otmgarments[]" id="otmgarments1" >
           <option value="AZ">Shirt</option>
           <option value="CO">Pant</option>
           <option value="ID">T-Shirt</option>
           <option value="MT">Sports Wear</option>
           <option value="NE">Jeans</option>       
         </select>
         
         
                                </td>
        
        
                                 <td>
            <select class="form-control" name="otmcolors[]" id="otmcolors1">
           <option value="Red">Red</option>
           <option value="Blue">Blue</option>
           <option value="White">White</option>
           <option value="Purple">Purple</option>
           <option value="Green">Green</option>       
           </select>
           
           
                                </td>
         
                                <td>  
          <select class="form-control" name="otmsize[]" id="otmsize1">
                                          <option value='xs'>XS</option>
                                          <option value='s'>S</option>
                                          <option  value='m'>M</option>
                                          <option  value='l'>L</option>
                                          <option  value='xl'>XL</option>
                                          <option  value='xxl'>XXL</option>
                                        </select>
          
          </td>
          
          
                                  <td><input type="text" value="1500" name="otmquantity[]"  id="otmquantity1" class="form-control" ></td>
          
                                  <td><span  id="tab1" onclick="duplicate(1)" class="btn  block btn-sm btn-danger">Duplicate</span></td>
          
         </tr>
        
        
                               </tbody> 
          
                            </table>
       
       
                          </div>        
                        </div>
```

Comment: you want to add another row in the table with the same user input? so that the user can add another item? Or you want to clone the entire table?

Comment: yes to what? I gave you two options: copy the single row or copy the entire table. What is the right one?

Comment: copy of entire table after user entered their inputs